# Can you guarantee an Inhuman baby?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, inhumans

Historically, Inhumans have selectively bred with each other to prevent unwanted mutations. But [the Inhumanity storyline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhumanity_%28comics%29) has shown us that there were Inhumans on Earth who never knew they were Inhumans.

It is fair to assume, then, that some Inhumans were breeding with regular humans.

How does Inhuman parentage work? Will the child of any Inhuman always be an Inhuman? Does it require both parents to be an Inhuman? Is it not guaranteed at all?

Comment: I don't think Inhumans born naturally in Marvel Cinematic Universe.

Comment: The mists are required to activate the mutations and powers, but Skye is an Inhuman born of two Inhumans.

Comment: But, the Obelisk mist rewrote entire cells of body which made Skye Inhuman.

Comment: Skye and Raina were only able to touch the Diviner without dying *because* they were Inhumans.

Comment: @phantom42 there was off-hand comment about the teleporting dude, that he was prepared basically from birth for his misting. Also, Raina's mother told her from a young age that she was 'special'. I took this to mean that parents "knew" their kids would also be Inhuman, though I don't know if it requires two Inhuman parents, since we don't know who Raina's parents were. (I also can't imagine them making all of their kids grab the Diviner on the off chance they won't die.)

Comment: @phantom42 It's not clear yet. Diviner just saw them special. What made them special may not be biological at all.

Comment: I can guarantee it if you’ve got the cash. PM me bro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: No, you cannot always guarantee that even two Inhumans will have an Inhuman child, but it's likely. And simply having the Inhuman gene does not guarantee Inhuman abilities.**

It's important to note that [**Inhumans**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Inhumans_(Inhomo_supremis)) are simply humans who carry the original genes added by the Kree millennia ago. Unlike the [X-gene](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Homo_superior), which guarantees a mutation of some sort if active, the Inhuman gene merely makes a mutation *possible* when (and IF) the subject is exposed to [Terrigen Mist](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Terrigen_Mist). Conceivably, an Inhuman could live out their entire lives as a human, never being exposed to the mist, and never knowing their true potential. Granted, however, that even without the mist exposure, a person with the Inhuman gene would be a little faster, a little stronger - not enough to appear superhuman, but certainly enough to excel when they apply themselves.

To your question, however, there is always an amount of uncertainty when it comes to genetic [heredity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredity) & [selective breeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_breeding). If two Inhumans produce offspring, the odds are certainly good that the offspring will be Inhuman as well. If an Inhuman and a human breed, it would depend on whether or not the Inhuman gene is [dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_(genetics)), which is something that we don't know. Potentially, at least, either pairing could result in a human child.

**UPDATE:** The events of the Infinity arc revealed that there had been unknown tribes of Inhumans breeding with normal humans throughout history. These pairings resulted in both human AND Inhuman offspring, with the Inhuman descendants not realizing their potential until Black Bolt

> detonated the [Terrigen Bomb](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Terrigen_Bomb), thus activating their dormant Inhuman genes. Thousands of people all over the Earth fell into Terrigen-activated cocoons, emerging later as fully transformed Inhumans.

[image]

Comment: “Unlike the X-gene” Totally unlike the X-gene! Completely different thing! Who are you calling? Seriously, there’s no need to get lawyers involved!